# Finding point in polygon in SQL Server?

Tags: polygon, point-in-polygon

I am downloading polygons from one of our feature layers on ESRI Online. I am creating sqlgeometry polygons in a table in MSSQL server.  Then I am downloading some points that come from another feature layer an storing those points in another table in MSSQL server.  However when I try to find the polygon for a point, I keep coming back with a null value.  From what I have read, it usually seems to be a problem with the order of points used to make the polygon.  Here is the order I am using.

Can anyone confirm if I am going in the correct direction or not?

I have tried to create the polygons the two different directions, but to no avail.  Maybe if I know I am going counter clockwise, I can focus on something else.

my polygon is constructed this way

-9963016.632 5551661.8461
 -9963013.4085 5551537.4852
 -9962845.196 5551391.701
 -9962564.1822 5551377.1886
 -9962477.7671 5551462.9439
 -9962380.3512 5551669.254
 -9963016.632 5551661.8461

Comment: can you post the SQL you're trying?

Comment: Can you also confirm the CRS of each of your layers?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the issue, all on me.  For some reason when I was creating the polygons I was using ERSI.spatialdata.wkid.  And when I was creating the points I was using the ESRI.spataildata.latestwkid.  Thank you very much for offering to help.  I changed both to use the .wkid and I am having success now.  Is that the correct choice, or should I be using the .latestwkid?

cheers bob